# Background doesn't show up in div

Tags: html, css

I made a div element with a unique class, then i gave the class a background image, but it doesn't show up. Even if I inspect the element everything is there, except that one line about the background image.

My code:

```
.godzillahatter{
background-image: url ("http://honlapkell.hu/verzio1/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/dalmatian-texture-1543316.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center; }
```

Inspect element:

```
.godzillahatter {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center center;
}
```

And the url: 
http://honlapkell.hu/verzio1/godzilla/

I have no idea what is the problem. The div element has content, but i tried that to give it height and width just for sure. I searched for solution, but none of them works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Change this

```
background-image: url ("http://honlapkell.hu/verzio1/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/dalmatian-texture-1543316.jpg");
```

to this

```
background-image: url("http://honlapkell.hu/verzio1/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/dalmatian-texture-1543316.jpg");
```

No space between `url` and `(`

Friendly piece of advice: 
Whenever you see a Yellow triangle like this in Chrome's inspector, it usually means your CSS syntax is wrong.
[image]

Comment: I use firefox which doesn't show yellow triangle if there is wrong something. It's a very usefull information, you've made my life easier. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

**Tested and verified!**

Use `background` property instead and remove the space after `url`.

```
background: url("http://honlapkell.hu/verzio1/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/dalmatian-texture-1543316.jpg");
```

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT:** As pointed out by others, it will work if you just remove the space after the `url`.

Comment: there's no *"also"*, the space cannot be there :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You got me. :)

Answer (score 1):

remove extra space after url

```
background-image: url ("http://honlapkell.hu/verzio1/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/dalmatian-texture-1543316.jpg");
```

should be

```
background-image: url("http://honlapkell.hu/verzio1/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/dalmatian-texture-1543316.jpg");
```

Comment: Who downvoted? The answer is pretty correct and was the first to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between url and the bracket:

```
background-image: url("http://honlapkell.hu/verzio1/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/dalmatian-texture-1543316.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-image`s url better to be without quotes, also if you use external source, use double slash `//` instead of `http://`

For less css code combine background properties into one line:

```
.godzillahatter
{
 background: url(//honlapkell.hu/verzio1/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/dalmatian-texture-1543316.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Comment: not the DV but quotes are pretty fine, also `//` will fail in a `file://` environment (although is good on localhost/server to let the browser get the right protocol).

Comment: @DominatorX we are talking about css. `//` is not a comment syntax there